# XML schema on a Symfony 1.4 Doctrine project

Tags: xml, schema, symfony-1.4

Do you know how can I use schema.xml on a Symfony 1.4 Doctrine project. I've deleted the yml schema under config/doctrine and replaced it with a XML schema as I was doing on Propel projects.

When running symfony doctrine:build-model task it only take into consideration the schema from sfDoctrineGuard plugin (which is a yml file).

Is there a possibility to use XML for the main schema config file?

Thanks,
Claudiu

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in 1.4 as far as I know. However, you can use doctrine:build-schema to 'reverse engineer' a schema.yml file from an existing database. You could also try a product called ORM Designer.